# How to close a question to new answers?

Tags: support, bounty, accepted-answer

This is related to a question with an accepted answer and a bounty awarded: [A snappy and inoffensive alternative for "calm your tits"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261990/a-snappy-and-inoffensive-alternative-for-calm-your-tits/264723#264723)

I would like to close my question, in the sense of not receiving any more answers or comments.  Is the ONLY way to do this to delete the question?

If so, then I propose to edit the question and state clearly that no more answers or comments are being sought.  Would that be kosher?

Comment: To close a question to new answers, you have to close the question, period. That can only be done by five users or a mod. A high-rep user or a mod can protect a question from new answers by low-rep users, but not from high-rep ones. And you cannot delete a question if it has upvoted answers, again a mod is needed.

Comment: The operation of the Stackexchange sites is that closing means that the community has decided that the question is not useful (or should be fixed to be made useful). You may be the author, but it's not up to you to decide to close or limit it (that is, once upvoted questions have been made; before that you can delete it yourself). But of course, making the request here advertises the fact that the question may well be seen to be closable (and deletable). So TLDR: your explicit request it's not kosher, but others can give you what you want if they agree.

Comment: Oh, and I agree, it should have been closed as off-topic from the beginning.

Comment: The harsh cold truth? After a day, or two at the most, no one will remember the question. No one will add comments, or provide answers because the question will no longer be on the first page, people will be busying themselves with answering the newest questions.

Comment: Thank you @Mari-LouA -- could you make this an answer, please?  Very reassuring.  I'm ready to forget that those tits, calm or uncalm, ever existed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - then why are the review queues so long? ;)

Comment: @medica precisely. It's because you get one or two users flagging posts and a small minority who go through that queue. That's why   it's so long. Voting to close is hardly thrilling stuff, is it? It's not an engaging activity, not for me anyway.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -  I was referring to new answers to old questions...

Comment: The "new answers" is a piffling number, and some questions do attract new answers more than others. This question is not one of them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - With all the polemics of the last few months, I have gotten in the habit of checking your activity timeline from time to time, because it's a useful way of getting up to speed efficiently.  To my dismay today, just as my suspension ended, I found that you have now received one too, and longer than mine.  I was sorry to see that. // You have helped with some key edits for me and I would be happy to reciprocate.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest that you familiarize yourself with the site as well as the Stack Exchange model: the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) will give you guidance on how to use this SE site (and others).

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) will give you an idea of what you can do at your present rep level, and what you can look forward to with more.

You cannot vote on your own question, though I believe with enough rep, you might be able to vote to close. Closed questions are subject to removal.

Remember, once you post a question or answer on an SE site, your post [kind of becomes community property](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/editing), to edit, delete, etc. Your "ownership" over it ceases once the community interacts with it in a significant manner. To shut down potentially better answers takes something away from the community which invested in the answer.

> If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

That also applies to closing, answering, etc. etc.

> If so, then I propose to edit the question and state clearly that no more answers or comments are being sought. Would that be kosher?

Since it neither chews its cud nor has split hooves, technically, no.<sup>*</sup>

Trying to change the SE model is a fruitless pursuit. (It isn't broken. It isn't implemented perfectly, but the model is just fine.) It would be better to properly use the system in place than to try to mold it to your desires.

<sub><sup>*</sup>I totally stole that from someone wittier than me.</sub>

Comment: So camel is allowed, but not rabbit? That's not convincing anyone to convert, you know.